# How to open two Solution in one Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am working on two different solutions, say, `Solution1` and `Solution2`. As these two solutions are dependent upon each other, I have to open two separate Visual Studio while developing.

It is really difficult to switch between these Visual Studio. I can't merge these two solutions into one as `Solution1` is being used by other projects and all are part of Source Control.

Just wondering, can I open both solutions in the same Visual Studio IDE? I searched a lot but no luck. Any suggestions on existing VS AddIn or how to develop it would also be helpful.

- Visual Studio version - 2012 Ultimate
- Source Control - TFS

Answer (score 3):

Create a third Solution C than includes project from both A and B: you can keep C as a local file i.e. you don't check it in version control if this can disturb the team.

Else you can open two instances of Visual Studio and switch at need: VS is smart enough to sense file system changes, but you have to be careful in saving before switching.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be within the same IDE instance?

You could right click the VS icon in the task bar, select "Visual Studio 20__", and you will have two seperate instances of VS. You can then open separate solutions in both, without merging the two under one solution.

This will eat up far more resources, however. The previous responses are preferable.

Comment: Yes, it does. That is clearly stated in the question.

Comment: Ignore the previous commenter, this is what I was looking for exactly.  So while you may not have perfectly answered the question you certainly answered what I came here looking fore.

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking is impossible and extremely dysfunctional.

The supported solution would be to add all of the projects from Solution B to Solution A. Then you can open a single solution with all of your work. If you want compartmentalisation within your solution you can use solution folders.

If you can you should have a separate solution for the core components and package them as a nuget package. Both of your other solutions can then take a dependency on that single shared package.

Comment: 1) It is not imposible, the mac version allows you to do exactly this
2) it is not dysfunctional. It is 1 more hierarchical step up. Nothing extreme.

Comment: It is impossible in Visual Studio (not Mac edition) and that is a deliberate design decision by the product team. It makes no sense to open two Solutions. That implies that your Solution does not contain everything that you need. Again to reiterate, dependencies between Solutions should be binary and not code. That is the dysfunction.

Answer (score -1):

open the solution 1 and right click and add the second solution. When you close the VS next time it will told you once to save the sln file. Do it for saving the settings in sln file.

Now everytime you will open sln1 will show you both project. It will not affect if you only move first project to pen drive or move to another computer. In case of 2nd project missing it will told you that 2nd project not found no more worries.

In case of **Source Control - TFS** I can't confirm how it work but their is some sollution for github (Which maybe hint anything for TFS).

The same trick can be applied but you don't need to push modified sln so this will not break anyone else's settings. If TFS store the files and code on the file system that you currently working then you can applied same trick to do applied this trick to that TFS project which is stored in your file system.

Answer (score -3):

1.open  solution1 in visual studio 2012 .
2.Right click on solution1 ,add existing project option.
3.select the solution2 .
4.Now  solution1 and solution2 file are same project.

Comment: This will change the .sln file of Solution1 and I can't no longer see the Solution2 in Visual Studio.

Comment: This also just adds all projects from 2 into 1. Not what the question is above,